# Firebase dynamic links aren't previewing pics in social media

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

My firebase dynamic link is not Generating link previews with social metadata - in dynamic links when you provide a link for 'si' metadata it is suppose to preview the pic in social media -- see Firebase documentation on preview pics for social media: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews

As you can see my link includes a valid link in the 'si' metadata link (&si=http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185//kq3ThsAeRNiS2VmFWQtvt3IJ1ab.jpg) see full link:

https://xe8re.app.goo.gl/?link=http://markatlarge.com/70573&isi=1387216991&ibi=com.markatlarge.BoobTube&si=http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185//kq3ThsAeRNiS2VmFWQtvt3IJ1ab.jpg

(dynamic link is for an ios app, should be clicked on an iphone app if you want to go to the app)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

your image is less than the recommended resolution according to the documentation
"The image should be at least 300x200 px, and less than 300 KB."

maybe thats the reason

I'm having a different issue where it's showing a cropped version of my image